# AS3: Socket timeout

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I get a vague "Socket timeout." error on occasion when I am loading my site.  I make various HTTP requests for PHP data and also am using a Loader() class instance.  Can anyone shed some light on where this error might be coming from?

I wish there was more of an indication of where the error stemmed from...

Here is my code that I am using.
There are multiple problems going on, but the most important is that catch{} catches an error on first load.  I have a fade in function that only works if the loader is fully loaded and I know that all of my URL links work, so it can't be that.

```
  public function loadImage(url:String):void 
  {
   this._imageURL = url;
   this.alpha = 1.0; //need this because we might have just faded the image out

   _ldr.alpha = 0.0;
   _prog.alpha = 1.0;
   _sqr.alpha = 0.0;

   try 
   {
    _ldr.close();
    _ldr.unload();
   }
   catch(e:Error)
   {
    trace("error in bmdisplay: " + e.message);
   }

   if(!_imageURL)
   {
    return;
   }

   _loaded = false;
   _ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
   _ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
   _ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
   _ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);
   _ldr.load(new URLRequest(_imageURL));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you provide more precise information on what you're actually loading and how?

You should be able to get the exact request throwing the error by listening for the `securityError` and `ioError` events on the `contentLoaderInfo` of the Loader object.

Something like this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorListener);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorListener);
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
loader.load(request);

...

private function errorListener(event:Event):void {
  var url_causing_the_error:String = LoaderInfo(event.target).loaderURL;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes; it's basically this code.  I'll post specifics by updating my post.

Comment: I know that it is the Loader() listener that is catching the error when I try to unload the image, but the error says something to the effect of "not loaded yet".  I would like to know how to escape this error if that's possible.

Comment: I am marking this answered because I am not sure that I fully understand the question I had asked.  Ultimately, I suppose I am asking if I have to do a check on whether or not an image has been loaded via a Bool.